# pydoc modules causing stack smashing

Tags: python, stack-overflow, pydoc

In order to see if a python module is installed, I ran the following on a terminal:

```
match=$(pydoc modules | grep $aModule)
```

Something went wrong, and now it always outputs this:

```
$ pydoc modules

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

Importing example package
demopkg1.__path__ before:
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyMOTW/pkgutil/demopkg1']

demopkg1.__path__ after:
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyMOTW/pkgutil/demopkg1']

Error: 'rho' must be an environment not NULL: detected in C-level eval
*** stack smashing detected ***: /usr/bin/python2.7 terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x45)[0xb73f3eb5]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x104e6a)[0xb73f3e6a]
/usr/lib/libR.so(+0x1c4964)[0xb2e93964]
/usr/lib/libR.so(+0xe5ddb)[0xb2db4ddb]
[0xbc246b4]
/usr/bin/python2.7(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x7c4)[0x812c6e4]
```

What does it mean? How can I fix it?